# What would be the benefit of using Async IO in my Python project?

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, async-await, python-asyncio

I have to devise a python program to communicate with a number, lets say 1000 devices via TCP in parallel. Each connection establishes a client connection and should start to communicate on a stream based way.

Until now I successfully employed select.select() to get notified when something arrives for reading or when writing has completed.

Now I learned a little about Python Async IO using async function definitions. I think it could write code more elegantly using this framework instead of re-using my old pattern.

However, I'm not sure, whether I should invest some time to learn it or just be satisfied with the old fashioned approach.

From a rough view I came to the conclusion that I could actually solve all I need with asyncio too.
However, to convince other people, what would be the real advantage beside using a "cool" framework?

EDIT:
I will never understand SO's policy regarding closing questions. Is this only a forum for experts on the highest top-level? I know that my question doesn't target a specialized and/or detailed question, but this is not a reason at all to close it.

Comment: In my experience it tends to create code that "reads" like synchronous code, which should be simpler to understand. that said, that's just my opinion, which in itself is a reason to close a question on SO :P

Comment: Why is it bad to ask about opinion? You give a good reason when saying code is better to understand.

Comment: Note that ``async`` frameworks use ``select.select`` (or the same underlying mechanism) behind the scenes. They are a different way to formulate a program you already have. Whether this way is "more elegant", whether you "should incest some time to learn it", whether you should "be satisfied with the old fashioned approach", or how to "convince other people" highly depends on you, your project and other people. It will not be possible to give an objective answer, or one applicable in general – which is what SO is about. Please see the [ask] page for what is considered on-topic.

Comment: Michael, this question wasn't closed because it's not "top-level", but because it's fairly abstract. Our sister site [programmers.se] might be a better place for this kind of question. See [their on-topic help page](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Async IO is not a part of python only. It is a programming paradigm, which is universally used across all programming languages. For instance, Async IO is one of the most highlighted feature of NodeJs. Therefore, in order to answer your question, yes, it is a long term investment if you study the Async IO as it is mandatory in most of the communication applications.

Comment: OT: Indeed, this answer does help. Don't know why question has been closed by other people, thinking that is is not of "highest quality" to fit into SO's policy.